# Why Process CPU is over 100%?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I've begun to track my asp.net application metrics, but for Servers -> Process CPU (avg) I'm getting values above 100% (194% or more). What does that mean?

Comment: where are you seeing it?

Comment: Servers -> Performance -> Activity by Role Instance grid, Process CPU (Avg) column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it means it's a multi-threaded process that's keeping 1.94 CPUs busy, on average.